# Calculate fine amount monthly according to Policy date and Installment Date

Tags: c#

Suppose a person buy a policy on `27/07/2016` his next installment date is `27/08/2016`.
If person not paid on installment date, 15 day extension is given to him for paying the installment.
If he failed to do so he had to give fine i.e. 2% of Policy Amount.

Now the scenario is -

27/08/2016 = Not Paid,
27/09/2016 = Not Paid,
27/10/2016 = Paid with fine of the previous two months.

So how to calculate this in c#

Comment: hope you are new to stackoverflow. please have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also, show us what you tried and where you are having problem.

Comment: I tried with  if (extdate < DateTime.Today)
                            {
                               var Other_Amount = (Convert.ToInt16(Policy_Amt.ToString().Trim()) * 2 ) / 100;
                            } But the problem is how to calculate previous  2 month fine according to date.

Comment: please share complete set of code snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ought to do it.

```
    public decimal CalculatePayment()
    {
        DateTime lastPaymentDueDate = new DateTime(2016, 7, 27);
        DateTime thisPaymentDate = new DateTime(2016, 10, 27);

        decimal policy = 10000.0M;
        decimal mthFee = 5000.0M;
        decimal mthFine = policy * 2.0M / 100.0M;
        decimal payAmount = 0.0M;
        DateTime nextPaymentDueDate = lastPaymentDueDate.AddMonths(1);

        int thisPayJulian = (int)thisPaymentDate.ToOADate();
        int nextDueJulian = (int)nextPaymentDueDate.ToOADate();

        if (thisPayJulian < nextDueJulian)
        {
            //nothing to pay
            return payAmount;
        }
        while (thisPayJulian - nextDueJulian > 15)
        {
            //deal with late payments
            payAmount += mthFine + mthFee;
            nextPaymentDueDate = nextPaymentDueDate.AddMonths(1);
            nextDueJulian = (int)nextPaymentDueDate.ToOADate();
        }
        if (thisPayJulian >= nextDueJulian)
        {
            //deal with regular payments
            payAmount += mthFee;
        }
        return payAmount;
    }
```

Obviously in the real world, the lastPaymentDueDate, thisPaymentDate, and policy, fee and fine percentages would all be parameters, rather than fixed variables as here, but I hope you get the idea.

However, I must re-iterate the other comments: in general people are not very willing to help, if you do not show rather more code of your own, than you have done.